# Weekly shuffle of array

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle, timed

I have a set of 4 HTML list items and I'd like to shuffle the order they appear in once a week. I was wondering if anyone out there had a nice, elegant solution to this?

As always, I'd be enormously grateful for any input you might have!

UPDATE:

Unfortunately, even with the necessary .htaccess overrides, I just can't get any srand() based solutions to work on this particular server sadly, but have the following which could be used instead - at the moment, it only returns one list item - how could I modify it to show the four required? Once again, any ideas would be gratefully received :)

```
function RandomList($TimeBase, $QuotesArray){

    $TimeBase = intval($TimeBase);

    $ItemCount = count($QuotesArray);

    $RandomIndexPos = ($TimeBase % $ItemCount);

    return $QuotesArray[$RandomIndexPos];

}

$WeekOfTheYear = date('W'); 

$RandomItems = array(
    "<li><a href=\"#northern-germany\" title=\"Northern Germany\">North</a></li>","<li><a href=\"#southern-germany\" title=\"Southern Germany\">South</a></li>","<li><a href=\"#western-germany\" title=\"Western Germany\">West</a></li>","<li><a href=\"#eastern-germany\" title=\"Eastern Germany\">East</a></li>");

print RandomList($WeekOfTheYear, $RandomItems);
```

Comment: I was going to post an answer that you should just use the week number as a seed value to `srand()` before calling `shuffle_array()`. This will yield the same sort order on a per-week basis. Unfortunately, it seems that this is not possible anymore since the seeding is performed automatically since PHP 4.2.0 :(

Comment: @jensgram: that only means it is not *necessary* anymore, not that it isn't possible. I.e. your solution will work. Add it as an answer.

Comment: @nikc Oh, good point. I just assumed that the seed was always called but never took the time to verify. The implementation has been posted in another answer so I wont bother to write the same :) (BTW: I talked about the non-existing `shuffle_array()` function. Obviously, I meant `shuffle()`, cf cbrandolino's answer.)

Comment: @nikc, actually it's very likely it won't work, due to the suhosin patch. See answer for details.

Comment: @cbrandolino: OP never mentioned the Suhosin patch. I tested it on an installment without it and it works just dandy.

Comment: @nikc: the patch is now default in most distributions. What I meant is, it may be that it just isn't possible, as opposed to just not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and - I guess - pretty elegant solution, which does not involve storing values in a database, setting up cronjobs and other boring stuff of the like.

Let's pretend you have your list elements in `$array`:

```
srand(date('W'));
shuffle($array);
srand();
```

Now your array is shuffled, and will be shuffled the same way until next Monday.

This has a problem, though: it does not work with the Suhosin patch (installed by default in Debian). Still, now that you know about `date('W')` it will be easy to come up with an alternate solution yourself.

EDIT: if you don't want to implement your own pseudorandom number generator but you have Suhosin installed, you can put the following line in your `.htaccess`:

`php_value suhosin.srand.ignore 0`

Comment: Thanks for the answer - looks good, but when I tried it, it seems to shuffle the order of the list items every time the page is refreshed! Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong: your php version must be shipped with the Suhosin patch. Check out the edit!

Comment: Rather than using srand, you could sort by a hash seeded with the week number (some testing required to ensure even probabilities if required) or you could sort by the modulus of the index + week number for a rotating stack.

Comment: @symcbean: He could use a disk and a magnetized needle, too. What advantage would your solution bring?

Comment: @cbrandolino: no obvious advantage - just pointing out that there are multiple ways to solve the problem.